# What is the Nutritional Value of Earth?

Tags: earth, food, bio-mechanics

This is Timmy. It’s a massive planetary eating monstrosity (don’t ask about Timmy), who likes to target inhabited planets. On this occasion, Timmy has chosen to feed on earth. What would the nutritional label of Earth be for Timmy? (Assume it eats earth in one sitting. Also assume he can fully process all the elements in earth for energy/nutritional needs)

Template (example, by all means make your own. I’m just copying an online one)

Calories:

 Total Fat:

Cholestrol:

Sodium:

Total Carbohydrates (Dietary Fibre and Sugar)

Protein

Vitamins and other nutrients

Comment: The Earth's crust has some fat, cholesterol, carbohydrates, proteins and vitamins, but in proportional quantities that are labeled as very poor to insignificant. The mantle and the core are essentially free of those. However, the core is very rich in iron. The levels of sodium are significant, but mostly in the crust and the mantle. The number of calories is well... astronomical for sure.

Comment: If I understand @Therac's chart correctly, humans constitute only about 0.01% of the biomass of Earth.  Even less when you include the vast amount of inorganic matter.  So does it really make a difference to include us or not?

Comment: How can you ignore the nutritional value of humans, yet look at total calories, fat, cholesterol and carbohydrates, fibre, sugar and protein, vitamins and other nutrients?

If you're going with Dan04's 'humans constitute only about 0.01% of the biomass of Earth' why did you not say that?

Comment: The *vast* majority of the Earth is silicates (rocks based on silicon-oxygen) and iron, while the biosphere is a **tiny film** just **1/20th of 1%** coating it.  Thus, Timmy had better be a [Doomsday Machine](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Doomsday_Machine_(episode)).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ignore the nutritional value of humans

The nutritional value of Earth is [to some extent humans.](https://www.pnas.org/doi/10.1073/pnas.1711842115)

[image: Biomass distribution]

At a planet-eating scale, you only care about total carbon.

Total carbon is 2 billion tons from animals plus 540 from plants, microorganism, and others.

The caloric content of animals will be about 5 kcal/gram * 2e9 tons = 5*1e6*2e9 = 1e16 = 10 quadrillion kcal.

Most plants and other lifeforms are not digestible, but if burned, they would add ~3.5 kcal/gram ~= 1.9 quintillion kcal total.

If Timmy needs heat, he'll absorb [Earth's internal heat budget](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth%27s_internal_heat_budget), which is mostly nuclear heat being released over time.

Comment: You know, the nutritional value of humans was going to be my next question. Nevermind.

Comment: @BlueSkinandGlowingRedEyes: [It's been calculated.](https://arstechnica.com/science/2017/04/counting-calories-of-going-cannibal-on-a-paleo-diet-human-flesh-is-just-meh/)  Turns out that humans aren't a very healthy food.

Comment: @dan04 That, and the whole "prions" thing.

Comment: Little random, but the final result is enough energy to completely atomize 433 Eros ten times over. Also about half a day's accumulated solar incidence on Earth. Bonkers.

Comment: What about all the coal, natural gas and oil underground?

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann It would strongly depend on whether they can be digested.

Comment: Timmy would need a significant part of the atmospheric oxygen to turn all these nutrients into energy.

Answer (score 4):

If you assume that the 545.2 Gt (Pg) biomass shown [in @Therac's answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/244771/what-is-the-nutritional-value-of-earth/244778#244778) has about the same overall macronutrient breakdown as the human food supply: 27% carbs, 20% fat, and 10% protein, then we have:

- Carbohydrates: 147.2 Pg
- Fat: 109 Pg
- Protein: 54.5 Pg

The standard calorie-counting formula is 9 per gram of fat plus 4 per gram of carbohydrates and proteins.  That works out to about 1.78×10<sup>18</sup> (kilo)calories in total.

Mineral-wise, Earth is extremely rich in iron and nickel (in the core) and silicon (in the mantle and crust).  But of these elements, only iron regularly occurs on nutrition labels, so I'll focus on that.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abundance_of_the_chemical_elements#Earth) says that iron is 32.1% of the planet's 5.97×10<sup>24</sup> kg mass, which works out to 1.916×10<sup>24</sup> kg.

The US FDA has a recommended daily value (DV) of 18 mg for iron, but that's based on a 2000-calorie diet.  If you assume that Earth's 1.78×10<sup>18</sup> (kilo)calories are a normal day's consumption for Timmy, then his DV for iron scales up to about 1.6×10<sup>10</sup> kg.  So Earth may have [way too much iron](https://www.healthline.com/nutrition/why-too-much-iron-is-harmful) for him.

Answer (score 3):

## Mostly Fat

The nutritional info of something depends on who is eating it. For a human being, wood has zero calories. It is made of cellulose. Essentially a carbohydrate that is too complex for a nonspecialised herbivore to bother with.

If you eat sawdust you will gain no energy. Your poo will be full of sawdust. However, for a woodlouse or elephant, that block of wood gets broken down like you break down your daily bean ration, and the poo has whatever remains once the chemical bonds in the wood are broken to release energy.

For a nuclear reactor, the block of wood has $mc^2$ energy like any other mass. This is what you get by converting the mass to energy.

Timmy the planet-gobbling super entity does not care about cellulose. He cares only about the most nutrient-dense hydrocarbons beneath the planet surface. We're talking oil, coal, and natural gas. There is more energy available from fossil fuels in the crust, compared to the thin layer of organic matter on the surface.

Timmy gobbles up these hydrocarbons like you gobble up bacon grease. Yum yum yum. He eats all life forms as well, as a matter of course. But they just get crunched up and pooed out undigested.